# Docker build waits for user input

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to *build python from source on docker*. I'm preparing the *dependencies*<sup>1</sup> from [here](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#linux).

```
$ type .\Dockerfile_07_python.txt
##############
#            #
# image name #
#            #
##############
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#################
#               #
# apt-get stuff #
#               #
#################
RUN \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install build-essential -y && \
apt-get install gdb -y
```

Apparently, the *docker build is stuck* because it waits for some weird (?) user input regarding my location (??):

```
$ docker build --tag host --file .\Dockerfile_07_python.txt .
 => [2/2] RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install build-essential -y && apt-get install gdb -y         225.5s
 => => # questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
 => => # the time zones in which they are located.
 => => #   1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
 => => #   2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
 => => #   3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
 => => # Geographic area:
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the actual dependency list is much longer, this is the minimal to trigger this behaviour

Comment: Set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`.  I tend to do it only for the single `apt-get install` command; `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes build-essential gdb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the environment variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND to 'noninteractive' and apt-get won't prompt you. Like this

```
##############
#            #
# image name #
#            #
##############
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#################
#               #
# apt-get stuff #
#               #
#################
RUN \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install build-essential -y && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install gdb -y
```